# How do you derive (~P -> Q) from P v Q as the premise using Fitch?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

I've been scratching my head about this for a while. I understand that the definition of an implication would make it ~~P v Q which is P v Q, but I can't figure out how to do it using the Fitch method. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The implication $A \to B$ is not defined to be $\neg A \lor B$ in Fitch.  You need to come up with a proof which assumes $\neg P$ and derives $Q$. From there, you should formalise the proof in Fitch.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at p. 208 of my *Introduction to Formal Logic* (the book is now freely downloadable from https://www.logicmatters.net/ifl) you'll find the proof you want [with the $P$ and $\neg P$ trivially the other way about].

I won't reproduce the proof here, however. That's because -- given that you have asked this elementary question -- I suspect that what you *really* need is a better grip on the basics about Fitch-style proofs. So can I suggest reading at least all of the two chapters on proofs with disjunctions and conditionals?